# How to get similar behaviour as the Java browsing perspective with two commonNavigator views?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I'd like to reproduce the behavior of the Java browsing perspective as so : the user select a file (`selectedFile`) from a Custom Common Navigator View (`VariabilityNavigator`) and it displays only the related files to that selection in another Custom Common Navigator View (`ConfigFileNavigator`). It refreshes automatically as the selection goes.

I use Common navigator because I want to display the package of the related files and not the other ones or the empty ones. That I coded fine.

Could you please walk me thru the steps to do that ? Here is how far I got..

1. I have successfully coded the first view `VariabilityNavigator`.
2. I thought I would use a filter `ConfigurationFilesFilter` to get the `selectedFile` and use it to filter the related files.
3. I can get the selection from the `VariabilityNavigator` within the select(...) of `ConfigurationFilesFilter`  code below
4. I then use it to filter the files I want to display using isRelatedToSelection. I haven't write that part yet, but it's not a problem for testing.

This method don't work for several reasons : it doesn't refresh and I have to click on the ConfigFileNavigator to get the result. What it should do : when I click on the first view and it should automatically display the result in the second view. Thanks for your help.

```java
public class ConfigurationFilesFilter extends ViewerFilter {

    String selectedFile;

    public ConfigurationFilesFilter() {

    }


    @Override
    public boolean select(Viewer viewer, Object parent, Object element) {
          selectedFile = getVariabilityNavigatorSelection();
         if (isChildElement(element)) {
            return handleChild(element);
        } else {
            // manipulate tree viewer based on select decision for the sub elements
            StructuredViewer sviewer = (StructuredViewer) viewer;
            ITreeContentProvider provider = (ITreeContentProvider) sviewer.getContentProvider();
            for (Object child : provider.getChildren(element)) {
                if (select(viewer, element, child)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param element
     * @return true to be displayed
     */
    private boolean handleChild(Object element) {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Check if an element is a java file and if it is related to the selection
     * 
     * @param element
     * @return boolean
     */
    private boolean isChildElement(Object element) {
        if (element instanceof IFile) {
            if (((IFile) element).getFileExtension().equals("java")) {
                return (isRelatedToSelection((IFile) element));
            }
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public String getVariabilityNavigatorSelection() {
        IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
        IViewPart viewPart = page.findView(VariabilityNavigator.ID);
        String VariabilityNavigatorSelection = "" ;
        if (viewPart == null) {
            VariabilityNavigatorSelection = "open Variability view. \r\nTo do so, open the menu as followed:\r\nWindow > Show view > Other... > SPL > Variability Navigator";
        } else {
            ISelectionProvider selProvider = viewPart.getSite().getSelectionProvider();
            IStructuredSelection sel = (IStructuredSelection) selProvider.getSelection();
            if (sel.isEmpty()) {
                VariabilityNavigatorSelection = "selection vide";
            }
            Iterator<?> i = sel.iterator();
            while (i.hasNext()) {
                final Object o = i.next();
                if (o instanceof IFile) {
                    VariabilityNavigatorSelection = ((IFile) o).getName();
                } else
                    VariabilityNavigatorSelection = "Please select a file";
            }
        }
        if (!VariabilityNavigatorSelection.isEmpty())
            printTrace("selectPrint = " + VariabilityNavigatorSelection);
        return VariabilityNavigatorSelection;
    }
```

Comment: You probably want to use the `public void addSelectionListener(String partId, ISelectionListener listener)` method of `ISelectionService` to set up a listener that is called whenever the selection changes.

Comment: I tried that solution but althought I can now get the different selections, I still have to reset the perspective to see the change. Here is the new code.
```java
viewPart.getSite().getWorkbenchWindow().getSelectionService().addSelectionListener(VariabilityNavigator.ID, new ISelectionListener() { public void selectionChanged(IWorkbenchPart part, ISelection selection) {//etc..```

Comment: Basically it does the same thing as before but it is cleaner. I certainly miss something, the way it works?. here is my code in its entire version if its any more helpful [link](https://github.com/vifeng/Eclipse_Plugin/blob/master/spl-development-plugins/src/spl/filter/ConfigurationFilesFilter.java)